# Redhat sso add external dependencies

Tags: keycloak

I have two jar files :

1. xxclient.jar
2. xxMain.jar

`Main.jar` is dependent on `client.jar` but when I execute service in `Main.jar` it is unable to find classes in `xxClient.jar` throws

> NoClassDefFoundError

I have added as module:

```
jboss-cli.bat --command="module add --name=Mymodule1 --resources=../providers/xxClient.jar" 

boss-cli.bat --command="module add --name= --Mymodule2 resources=../providers/xxMain.jar --dependencies= Mymodule1"
```

Also added module name in `standalone.xml`

Any help will be much appreciated

Comment: `NoClassDefFoundError` might need more context, like for which class (copy paste a bit more from the Exception stack been printed). - also try to apply proper formatting so I can distinguish code parts (or in your case your cor .bat files or command line.

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed it.

The only way is to add a **dependency jar is as a module** but you need to add all the dependencies in module.xml file as well as.

```
jboss-cli.bat --command="module add --name=Mymodule1 --resources=../providers/xxClient.jar"
```